# How to debug windows store app OnActivated event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-debugging

I setup my windows 8 store app associated a URI. I'm trying to set a break point inside OnActivated method. The problem is when I try to open a URI, it will open the app I have deployed in my dev pc and will not launch the visual studio with debugger. Anyone knows how to setup visual studio (2013) to make the app launch within the debugger when OnActivated is called?

thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to your project's properties, then go to `Debug`.

In the `Start Action` section is a check box that reads `Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts.` Check this.

Start debugging. Your app will not launch.

Open your app via the method you desire (such as by file protocol). The debugger will attach and you will be able to step into the `OnActivated` section.